Can you determine if a sympy expression has an explicit time dependence?
Can you determine if a sympy expression has an explicit time dependence?
For example this example does have an explicit time dependence:
import sympy as sp
expr = sp.sympify("Add(Symbol('t'), Function('y')(Symbol('t')))")

But this example does not (even though t is a parameter of the y function.
import sympy as sp
expr = sp.sympify("Add(Integer(2), Function('y')(Symbol('t')))")

EDIT: Here are two example expressions, note the derivatives.
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import k, t
yt=Function('y')(t)
# has explicit t dependence
eq1 = t + yt.diff(t)

# has no explicit t dependence
eq2 = k + yt.diff(t)


One possibly approach is to code a function that, given some assumptions, looks for the terms of the expression and attempts to determine the time dependency. Something like this:
from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef

def is_time_dependent(expr):
    if not isinstance(expr, sp.Add):
        return False
    # find all applied undefined functions, select the first
    f = set([a for a in expr.args if isinstance(a, AppliedUndef)]).pop()
    if not f:
        return False
    # select time: assume the applied undefined function only
    # have a single parameter
    t = f.args[0]
    # find all other terms of the expression
    rhs = set(expr.args).difference([f])
    return any(a.has(t) for a in rhs)

expr = sp.sympify("Add(Integer(2), Function('y')(Symbol('t')))")
print(is_time_dependent(expr))
# out: False

expr = sp.sympify("Add(Symbol('t'), Function('y')(Symbol('t')))")
print(is_time_dependent(expr))
# out: True

Note: this was only tested on your two expressions, so it may don't work for other cases. But you got the idea.

This seems to throw an exception. I added the example that throws to my original post.

I don't really understand why 2+f(t) is deemed time independent, but if you mean that you only want to consider time dependence independent of time in AppliedUndef functions, then I would just mask off all such functions and query the masked expression for t:
>>> from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import *
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> eq = f(t)
tdep = lambda eq: t in eq.replace(
    lambda x:isinstance(x, AppliedUndef),
    lambda x:x.func(*[Dummy() for i in x.args])).free_symbols
>>> tdep(eq)
False
>>> tdep(eq+1/t)
True


Thanks! Yes I know what you mean, just not sure how to describe excluding the functional dependencies on t. For context it's for determining if energy is conserved looking at a Hamiltonian. Which requires checking for this 'explicit' time dependence.

I think maybe this doesnt handle derivatives. I added an example in my original post.

For some reason Derivative(f(x), t).has_free(t) is True even though the free symbols of the same is just {x}. I am guessing that this is a bug in has_free. I modified my answer to directly use free_symbols and the additional expression behave as you expect.
